# Cannot access method by reference

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

When i access the method directly on the `PagerAdapter` creation i have the `getViewAtPosition()` method. When i try it using the reference, i can't. What may i do to get acecces by the reference?

Here i can:
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUvgD.png):[image]

Here i can't:
  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGBVr.png): [image]

```
public class CardapioRU extends Fragment {

private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_ru, container, false);

    mPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapterRU(inflater);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    return rootView;
}

}
```

.

```
public class PagerAdapterRU extends PagerAdapter {

private View domingo = null;
private View segunda = null;

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
public PagerAdapterRU(LayoutInflater inflater) {
    domingo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ru_domingo, null);
    segunda = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ru_segunda, null);
}

public View getViewAtPosition(int position) {
    View view = null;
    if (position == 0) {
        view = domingo;
    }
    if (position == 1) {
        view = segunda;
    }
    ;
    return view;
};

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    View view = getViewAtPosition(position);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can't and it's not just an IDE quirk?

Comment: Ya, could be just android studio.  Sometimes it will just not assist in putting it in, sometimes I have to put it in completely and compile before it considers it valid.

Comment: wasn't a IDE problem, Eclipse is all right, the answer is above, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getViewAtPosition()` is a method of `PagerAdapterRU`.

On the first screenshot you're calling a method directly on your `PagerAdapterRU` instance, but on the second screenshot you're calling it on a `PagerAdapter`.

It doesn't matter how you've initialized it, you've declared it as a `PagerAdapter`, so you have access to the methods of a `PagerAdapter`.

To have access to the methods of the subclass, declare it with the type of the subclass.

Change the following:

```
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
```

To this:

```
private PagerAdapterRU mPagerAdapter;
```

And you'll be able to call `getViewAtPosition()` on `mPagerAdapter`.

Comment: Probably that's the answer. Lack of attention of mine. I will test later when i'm at home and, if so, i accept the answer.